# Data Integration Rules

Tags: custom-object, data-integration-rule

Accessing "Settings" -> "Data Integration Rules" and I have access to the Data Integration Rules. It shows the edition for the type of Account objects. I want to be able to activate for a custom object.

Answer (score 0):

Data Integration Rules aren't available for Custom Objects, only the Account, Contact and Lead objects.

I found one very hacky way of using these to update Custom Objects using a temporary Contact record, but I wouldn't suggest doing this as it's likely to have other impacts/run the risk of reducing data quality in whatever standard object you're using as a proxy record. For you information, that can be found [here](https://www.issacc.com/get-geolocation-for-your-custom-object-in-salesforce/).